# Create action in Windows Task Scheduler run commands for dtsx packages

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, windows-task-scheduler, ssis-2017

I am wondering the correct way to navigate to a dtsx package deployed on my SQL Server. While creating the action, so far I have the Program/script to open SQL.

```
"CD\C\Program Files (x86)Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn|ManagementStudio\DTExecUI.exe"
```

My issue is finding the path to the package that is deployed. What arguments can I add to continue navigating through the packages in the SSIS catalog?

Comment: Why would you use Task Scheduler rather than SQL Server Agent?

Comment: It is not my decision. I would rather use the agent as well, but I am required to to use the Task Scheduler. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First of all, i think that it is better to work with SQL server agent to schedule a ssis package job*

---

To run a package from a server using Task scheduler, you can use `DTExec` utility.

*example*

```
dtexec /ISServer "\SSISDB\Project1Folder\Integration Services Project1\Package.dtsx" /Server "localhost"
```

**References**

- [Run an SSIS package from the command prompt with DTExec.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-cmdline)
- [Scheduling SQL Server Integration Services Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/scheduling-sql-server-integration-services-packages).
- [dtexec utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Usin dtexec with package on IS Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2011/07/24/using-dtexec-with-packages-on-the-is-server/)